# Decode the chmod

Tags: code-golf, parsing

### Challenge

Given a three digit octal permissions number, output the permissions that it grants.

### chmod

On UNIX OSes file permissions are changed using the `chmod` command. There are few different ways of using chmod, but the one we will focus on today is using octal permissions.

The three digits in the permissions number represent a different person:

- The first digit represents the permissions for the **user**
- The second digit represents the permissions for the **group**
- The last digit represents the permissions for **others**

Next, each digit represents a permission as shown below in:

```
Key: number | permission

7 | Read Write and Execute
6 | Read and Write
5 | Read and Execute
4 | Read only
3 | Write and Execute
2 | Write only
1 | Execute only
0 | None
```

### Input

The input will be the three digit number as a string, e.g.:

```
133
```

or

```
007
```

This will be passed either via STDIN or via function arguments.

### Output

Your output should be the different permissions for each of the user, the group and the others. You must display this information like so:

```
User:   ddd
Group:  ddd
Others: ddd
```

Where there are three spaces after `User`, two spaces after `Group` and one space after `Others`. You replace `ddd` with the permissions information.

Your output may be to STDOUT or as a returned string.

### Examples

**Input:** 666

**Output:**

```
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read and Write
Others: Read and Write
```

---

**Input:** 042

**Output:**

```
User:   None
Group:  Read only
Others: Write only
```

---

**Input:** 644

**Output:**

```
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read only
Others: Read only
```

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: What are the specifications of the input?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Just the three digit number

Comment: You mean as a decimal integer only, so 042 would be received as 42?

Comment: @Jonathan No, it's a string input so it'd be 042

Comment: Are we allowed to have an int-array or three ints as input? Or we need to use the String and then parse to digits?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You need to have a string and parse the digits

Comment: Is using a tab instead of [3|2|1] spaces allowed?

Comment: @aross No, you must use spaces since all of the answers have used spaces

Comment: @BetaDecay Except the PHP one :)

Comment: @aross Oh right haha

Comment: The top JavaScript entry currently also uses a tab at time of writing.

Comment: The output looks right with a tab character, so why not use it? Just to penal languages that need more bytes to pad a string?

Comment: @Titus No, because I specified to use spaces, which almost every other submission does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>89</s> 87 bytes

```
”‚Ý:‚Ù:ˆ†:”ð¡v”Šª0ÍÃ20‡í20‡í1ÍÃ0‚Ø20‚Ø1ÍÃ0‚Ø1‡í0‚Ø‡í1ÍÃ”2ð'€É«:1ð'€ƒ«:0ð«¡¹Nèèð3N-×ìyì,
```

<s>Summons the **Cthulhu** encoding.</s> Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCd4oCaw5064oCaw5k6y4bigKA64oCdw7DCoXbigJ3FoMKqMMONw4MyMOKAocOtMjDigKHDrTHDjcODMOKAmsOYMjDigJrDmDHDjcODMOKAmsOYMeKAocOtMOKAmsOY4oChw60xw43Dg-KAnTLDsCfigqzDicKrOjHDsCfigqzGksKrOjDDsMKrwqHCuU7DqMOow7AzTi3Dl8OsecOsLA&input=MDQy)

Answer (score 14):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>165</s> 161 bytes

```
n=>[0,1,2].map(i=>(s='User:  3Group: 68Others:58None576Read48Write476Execute475and4576only'.split(/(\d+)/))[i*2]+s[n[i]*2+1].replace(/./g,c=>' '+s[c*2])).join`
`
```

*Edit: +1 byte to fulfill the "no tab" rule*

#### Examples

```js
let f =
n=>[0,1,2].map(i=>(s='User:  3Group: 68Others:58None576Read48Write476Execute475and4576only'.split(/(\d+)/))[i*2]+s[n[i]*2+1].replace(/./g,c=>' '+s[c*2])).join`
`
console.log(f("666"));
console.log(f("042"));
console.log(f("644"));
console.log(f("137"));
```

Comment: You can gain a few bytes by rearranging the array (and maybe separating the numbers from the strings). +1 for the idea.

Comment: @Titus - I've to admit that I fail to see a rearrangement that saves some bytes. Also, the numbers have to be treated as strings so that `replace()` works on them without coercing. But I may be missing your point.

Comment: @Titus - Something like `'User3Group68Others58None576Read48Write476Execute475and4576only'.split(/(\d+)/)` might work. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I was misunderstanding them; thought they were octal values. :) But your new idea is not bad either.

Comment: Challenge output requires spaces instead of tabs as it is currently written.

Comment: @Mwr247 - This is apparently still under discussion, but I did the update anyway (+1 byte).

Answer (score 13):

### GNU sed, <s>187 163</s> 158 (157+1) bytes

Run with *-r* (ERE regexp). File contains no trailing newline.

```
s/(.)(.)/User:   \1\nGroup:  \2\nOthers: /g
s/[4-7]/Read &/g
s/[2367]/Write &/g
s/[1357]/Execute &/g
s/(\w) (\w+) [1-7]/\1 and \2/g
s/[1-7]/only/g
s/0/None/g
```

Comment: Nice approach but you can save about 20 bytes by removing the digits when you add the `and` or `only`.

Comment: @Neil there :) incorporated your suggestion for a very significant save.

Comment: The first line could be just: `s/(.)(.)/User:   \1\nGroup:  \2\nOthers: /`. Some more bytes could be saved by porting to Perl, which has `\d` and `\K`.

Comment: @ninjalj good point. I'll stick to sed since I don't know Perl, and I'm sure there'd be other tricks to pull there to make it even shorter, outside of s/// replacements.

Comment: In the 3-last substitution, you can use a word boundary and the multiline flag to save some bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>100 91</s> 85 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup><s>Almost certainly golfable - 91 bytes, what?!</s></sup>  **8 months and 6 wisdom bytes!**
- 1. more string compression;
- 2. remove the post-ordinal decrement by 48 since indexing is modular;
- 3. use better tacit chaining).

-9 bytes with the kind help of @Lynn running string compressions for me

```
,“£ɱ~»
Ñ
ṖK,“ and”,Ṫ
LĿK
7RBUT€Uị“ØJƓ“¥Ị£“¤/¡»Ç€“¡*g»ṭ
“ṖŒhJ"ỵd¡»ḲðJ4_⁶ẋ⁸,"j€”:ż⁹Oị¢¤Y
```

Test it at **[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/nUcOcQ4tPbqw7tJvr8ESuhzuneYOEFBLzUh41zNV5uHMVl8@R/d5c5kFOoSGPmtaEPtzdDZQ/PMPr2GSQ1qUPd3cdWgxiLdE/tPDQ7sPtQEUg7kKt9EO7H@5cywXkAE09OinDS@nh7q0pIEUPd2w6vMHr4c5Zjxq3PdzV/ahxh45SFljfXKujex417vQH2nJo0aElkf///1cyMDFSAgA)**

How?

```
,“£ɱ~» - Link 1: pair with the string "Only"

Ñ - Link 2: call next link

ṖK,“ and”,Ṫ - Link 3: insert " and" between the last two elements of x
Ṗ           - x[:-1]
 K          - join with spaces
   “ and”   - the string " and"
          Ṫ - x[-1]
  ,      ,  - pair

LĿK - Link 4: call appropriate link and add missing spaces
L   - length
 Ŀ  - call link at that index
  K - join the result with spaces

7RBUT€Uị“ØJƓ“¥Ị£“¤/¡»Ç€“¡*g»ṭ - Link 5: construct all 8 cases
7R                            - range of 7: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  B                           - binary (vectorises): [[1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
   U                          - reverse (vectorises): [[1],[0,1],[1,1],[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]
    T€                        - indexes of truthy values for each: [[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
      U                       - reverse (vectorises): [[1],[2],[2,1],[3],[3, 1],[3,2],[3,2,1]]
        “ØJƓ“¥Ị£“¤/¡»         - list of strings: ["Execute","Write","Read"]
       ị                      - item at index (vectorises): [["Execute"],["Write"],["Write","Execute"],["Read"],["Read","Execute",["Read","Write"],["Read","Write","Execute"]]
                     Ç€       - call the previous link for each
                       “¡*g»  - the string "None"
                            ṭ - tack (Jelly is 1-based so the 8th item will be indexed as 0)

“ṖŒhJ"ỵd¡»ḲðJṚ⁶ẋ⁸,"j€”:ż⁹Oị¢¤Y - Main Link: parse input and make the result. e.g.: "042"
“ṖŒhJ"ỵd¡»                     - dictionary compression of "User Group Others"
          Ḳ                    - split at spaces -> ["User","Group","Others"]
           ð                   - dyadic chain separation, call that g (input as right)
            J                  - range of length of g -> [1,2,3]
             Ṛ                 - reverse -> [3,2,1]
              ⁶                - literal space
               ẋ               - repeat -> ["   ","  "," "]
                ⁸              - chain's left argument, g
                  "            - zip with:
                 ,             -   pair -> [["User","   "],["Group","  "],["Others"," "]]
                     ”:        - literal ':'
                   j€          - join for €ach -> ["User:   ","Group:  ","Others: "]
                            ¤  - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                        ⁹      - chain's right argument, the input string -> "042"
                         O     -   cast to ordinal (vectorises) -> [48, 52, 50]
                           ¢   -   call last link (5) as a nilad  -> ["Execute Only","Write Only","Write and Execute","Read Only","Read and Execute","Read and Write","Read Write and Execute","None"]
                          ị    -   index into (1-based & modular) -> ["None","Read Only","Write Only"]
                       ż       - zip together -> [["User:   ","None"],["Group:  ","Read Only"],["Others: ","Write Only"]]
                             Y - join with line feeds -> ["User:   ","None",'\n',"Group:  ","Read Only",'\n',"Others: ","Write Only"]
                               - implicit print:
                                             >>>User:   None
                                             >>>Group:  Read Only
                                             >>>Others: Write Only
```

Answer (score 6):

## C# 214 Bytes

```
string h(string y){string e="Execute ",r="Read ",w="Write ",O="Only",a="and ";var z=new[]{"None",e+O,w+O,w+a+e,r+O,r+a+e,r+a+w,r+w+a+e};return$"User:   {z[y[0]-'0']}\nGroup:  {z[y[1]-'0']}\nOthers: {z[y[2]-'0']}";}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 185 bytes

```
@(n)fprintf('User:   %s\nGroup:  %s\nOthers: %s',{'Read Write and Execute','Read and Write','Read and Execute','Read only','Write and Execute','Write only','Execute only','None'}{56-n})
```

Create anonymous function that takes the input as a string: '042'. Convert it to an array: `(56-'042)' = [0 4 2]`. Use this as multiple cell indices to index the cell array with `Read Write and Execute','Read and Write', ...`. Uses `fprintf` to output the three strings, with the appropriate categories: `User:`   , `Group:`   and `Others:` .

I tried finding a way to store `Execute`, `Write`, `Read` as separate words and concatenate as needed, but this turned out longer than the naive approach.

**Examples:**

```
1> f('000')
User:   None
Group:  None
Others: None
2> f('042')
User:   None
Group:  Read only
Others: Write only
```

[**Try it online.**](https://ideone.com/VpSVW6)

Comment: You can save a few bytes using `strsplit('Read Write and Execute*Read and Write*Read and Execute*Read only*Write and Execute*Write only*Execute only*None','*')` instead of the cell array literal

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>189</s> 168 bytes

```
[char[]]$args[0]|%{('User','Group','Others')[$i++]+":`t"+('None','Read','Write','Execute','only','and')[(0,(3,4),(2,4),(2,5,3),(1,4),(1,5,3),(1,5,2),(1,2,5,3))[$_-48]]}
```

Loops through the input `$args[0]` as a `char`-array. Each iteration, we index into an array with `$i++` (defaults to `0`) to select `User`, `Group`, or `Others`, concatenate that with a colon and a tab, and concatenate that with another array index.

Here's the magic. We implicitly cast the `char` to an `int` and subtract `48` (i.e., turning ASCII `48` (`"0"`) into `0`), choosing the appropriate wording as an array of `int`s. That array is subsequently used as the index into the `'None','Read','Write','Execute','only','and'` array. Since the default [`$ofs`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx) (Output Field Separator) is a space, this correctly inserts spaces between the array elements when stringified (which happens when it concatenates to the left).

These three strings are left on the pipeline, and output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\decode-the-chmod.ps1 '123'
User:   Execute only
Group:  Write only
Others: Write and Execute
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Straw](http://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw), 193 bytes

```
((01234567)((None)(Execute only)(Write only)(Write and Execute)(Read only)(Read and Execute)(Read and Write)(Read Write and Execute)))::~<:{-¢(User:   ),+>
>}:{-¢(Group:  ),+>
>}-¢(Others: ),+>
```

[Try it online](http://straw.tryitonline.net/#code=KCgwMTIzNDU2NykoKE5vbmUpKEV4ZWN1dGUgb25seSkoV3JpdGUgb25seSkoV3JpdGUgYW5kIEV4ZWN1dGUpKFJlYWQgb25seSkoUmVhZCBhbmQgRXhlY3V0ZSkoUmVhZCBhbmQgV3JpdGUpKFJlYWQgV3JpdGUgYW5kIEV4ZWN1dGUpKSk6On48OnstwqIoVXNlcjogICApLCs-Cj59OnstwqIoR3JvdXA6ICApLCs-Cj59LcKiKE90aGVyczogKSwrPg&input=)

Push 3 times a conversion table on the first stack, switch to the second stack, convert each number using the conversation table and print.

Answer (score 2):

**PHP, <s>169</s> 159 bytes**

```
foreach([User,Group,Others]as$i=>$u){echo"
$u: ";for($n=[5,33,34,66,35,67,131,531][$i]];$n;$n>>=3)echo["and",Execute,Write,Read,only,None][$n&7]," ";}
```

takes string as command line argument: `php -r '<code>' <argument>`,
prints a leading newline instead of a trailing one

Thanks to Jörg for pointing out my bugs - and for the `\t`.

## PHP, 169 bytes

with the new restriction: (tab character forbidden)

```
foreach(['User:  ','Group: ','Others:']as$i=>$u){echo"
$u";for($n=[5,33,34,66,35,67,131,531][$argv[1][$i]];$n;$n>>=3)echo' ',['and',Read,Write,Execute,only,None][$n&7];}
```

This is 1 byte shorter than with `str_pad`, because of the additional blank it would require.

**breakdown**

```
foreach([User,Group,Others]as$i=>$u)
{
    echo"\n$u:\t";                      // print newline, who, blanks
    for($n=[5,33,34,66,35,67,131,531]   // octal values for words indexes
        [$argv[1][$i]]                  // (last word=highest digit)
        ;$n;$n>>=3)                     // while value has bits left
        echo['and',Execute,Write,Read,only,None][$n&7]," "; // print that word
}
```

To create the array for `$n`, use this:

```
$b=[[5],[1,4],[2,4],[2,0,1],[3,4],[3,0,1],[3,0,2],[3,2,0,1]];
foreach($b as$i=>$a){for($v=$j=0;$a;$j+=3)$v+=array_shift($a)<<$j;echo"$v,";}
```

Comment: foreach(['User','Group','Others']as$i=>$u){echo"\\n$u:\\t"; saves some bytes and the output for 3,4,6 is wrong

Comment: This is the right order [5,33,34,66,35,67,131,531] nice idea

Comment: I have forget 'User' to User for exmple saves the next 6 Bytes you want to beat JavaScript do it

Comment: @JörgHülsermann: I was about to adopt the "\t" anyway; thanks. +1 for that :) Good eye on the `33`!

Comment: for 346 our output is User: Read and Write 
Group: Execute only 
Others: Write and Execute it should User: Write and Execute
Group: Read Only
Others: Read and Write

Comment: @JörgHülsermann: Fixed. These are the correct values: `[5,33,34,66,35,67,131,531]`

Comment: How exactly are you supposed to pass the argument? Your golfed version seems to be incorrect

Comment: No using of tabs either

Comment: Dear downvoter: why?

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 186 Bytes

```
s=zip(words"7654 6 7632 753 7531 0 421")(words"Read and Write and Execute None only")
m c=mapM_(\(x,y)->putStrLn(x++unwords[b|(a,b)<-s,elem y a]))$zip["User:   ","Group:  ","Others: "]c
```

Example:

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( decCh.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> m "654"
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read and Execute
Others: Read only
```

Only Prelude used. Am I doing this right?

Ungolfed:

```
s = zip (words "7654 6 7632 753 7531 0 421")
        (words "Read and Write and Execute None only")

ps y = unwords [b|(a,b)<-s,elem y a] -- build permissions string
pp (x,y) = putStrLn $ x ++ ps y -- print user + permission

m c =   let up = zip ["User:   ","Group:  ","Others: "] c -- pair user and permission
        in mapM_ pp up --print each
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>190</s> 185 bytes

```
def f(i):
 r,w,a,x,o,g="Read ","Write ","and ","Execute ","only",["User:  ","Group: ","Others:"];p=["None",x+o,w+o,w+a+x,r+o,r+a+x,r+a+w,r+w+a+x]
 for z in 0,1,2:print g[z],p[int(i[z])]
```

Leaves a trailing space if Execute or Write are at the end of the line but I didn't see that this wasn't allowed.

**EDIT** Saved 5 bytes by changing range(3) to 0,1,2 and checking byte count on my Linux laptop instead of my Windows one (\n = \r\n or the other way round. I can never remember which).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>240</s> <s>239</s> <s>238</s> <s>237</s> 228 bytes

I thought I’d finally give this cold golf thing a go. <s>Hopefully trailing whitespace is allowed.</s> (fixed, and in the process saved a byte)

```py
i=0
def a(b):
 for d in 4,2,1:
    if b&d:yield('Execute','Write','Read')[d/2]
for k in raw_input():
 b,q=list(a(int(k))),' and';e=len(b)
 if e:b[~e/2]+=(' only',q,q)[e-1]
 print'UGOsrteohrue:pr :s  :'[i::3],' '.join(b)or None;i+=1
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and nice first answer!

Comment: I have shamelessly replaced the range(3) in my Python 2 answer to 0,1,2 after reading through your code. Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

## bash - <del>221</del> 213 bytes

`GNU bash, version 4.3.46`

```
l=("User:   " "Group:  " "Others: ")
o=\ only;a=" and ";x=Execute;w=Write;r=Read
b=(None "$x$o" "$w$o" "$w$a$x" "$r$o" "$r$a$x" "$r$a$w" "$r $w$a$x")
for c in `echo $1|grep -o .`;{ echo "${l[$((z++))]}${b[$c]}";}
```

Unclear if this can be condensed any further, at least not without fundamentally changing the approach here (splitting up input and using it as an index to the array `${b}` that holds the corresponding strings).

Comment: It's shorter with `\ only` expanded inline. `grep -o .<<<$1` is shorter than `echo $1|grep -o .`, but reading the input from stdin with `while read -n1 c` is better. Array indexes have arithmethic context in bash, so `${l[z++]}` works. `l` would be shorter as a string, which would be accessed as `${l:z++*8:8}` (offset and length have arithmethic context). Another byte can be sh?aved by reading the whole mode in `c`, expanding "User:   ", ... inline and making judicious use of parameter expansions.

Comment: For an end result of: `a=" and ";x=Execute;w=Write;r=Read;b=(None $x\ only $w\ only "$w$a$x" $r\ only "$r$a$x" "$r$a$w" "$r $w$a$x");read c;echo "User:   ${b[${c%??}]}\nGroup:  ${b[${c:1:1}]}\nOthers: ${b[${c:2}]}"` (replace \n with literal newlines).

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <strike>213</strike> <strike>209</strike> <strike>208</strike> <strike>188</strike> 186 bytes

```
function(d){a=" and ";r="Read";w="Write";e="Execute";v=";";o=" only";c=["None",e+o,w+o,w+a+e,r+o,r+a+e,r+a+w,r+" "+w+a+e];return"User: "+c[d[0]]+"\nGroup: "+c[d[1]]+"\nOthers: "+c[d[2]]}
```

Saved 20 bytes thanks to Dada!

Comment: I might be mistaken, but shouldn't your array be in the opposite order? If I call b("000"), it returns "Read Write and Execute" while one could expect "None"...

Comment: And I'm pretty sure this could be more golfed. For instance, a 191 byte version : `function b(p){a=" and ";r="Read";w="Write";e="Execute";v=";";o=" only";c=["None",e+o,w+o,w+a+e,r+o,r+a+e,r+a+w,r+" "+w+a+e];return"User:   "+c[p[0]]+"\nGroup:  "+c[p[1]]+"\nOthers: "+c[p[2]]}`.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, <s>217</s> <s>207</s> 205 bytes

```
def c(m){def i=0,e='Execute',w='Write',r='Read',o=' only',a=' and ';m.each{println(['User:   ','Group:  ','Others: '][i++]+['None',"$e$o","$w$o","$w$a$e","$r$o","$r$a$e","$r$a$w","$r $w$a$e"][it as int])}}
```

ungolfed:

```
def c(m) {
  def i=0,e='Execute',w='Write',r='Read',o=' only',a=' and ';
  m.each{
    println(['User:   ','Group:  ','Others: '][i++]+['None',"$e$o","$w$o","$w$a$e","$r$o","$r$a$e","$r$a$w","$r $w$a$e"][it as int])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>300</s> 284 bytes

```
String c(String s){char[]a=s.toCharArray();return"User:   "+f(a[0])+"Group:  "+f(a[1])+"Others: "+f(a[2]);}String f(int i){return new String[]{"None","Execute only","Write only","Write and Execute","Read only","Read and Execute","Read and Write","Read Write and Execute"}[i%48]+"\n";}
```

Direct approach for now. Will try to come up with a more generic approach to reuse the words.

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/TKs7ZT)

```
class M{
  static String c(String s){
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    return "User:   " + f(a[0]) + "Group:  " + f(a[1]) + "Others: " + f(a[2]);
  }

  static String f(int i){
    return new String[]{ "None", "Execute only", "Write only", "Write and Execute", "Read only", "Read and Execute", "Read and Write", "Read Write and Execute" }
      [i % 48] + "\n";
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("666"));
    System.out.println(c("042"));
    System.out.println(c("644"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read and Write
Others: Read and Write

User:   None
Group:  Read only
Others: Write only

User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read only
Others: Read only
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 322 <strike>337 348</strike> bytes

That's for sure not the shortest version, but I tried solving this problem using bitwise operators since the `chmod` values are actually bit flags. Also C# is probably not the best golfing language :D

```cs
string P(string s){Func<int,string>X=p=>{var a=new List<string>();if((p&4)>0)a.Add("Read");if((p&2)>0)a.Add("Write");if((p&1)>0)a.Add("Execute");return a.Count>1?string.Join(" ",a.Take(a.Count-1))+" and "+a.Last():a.Count>0?a.First()+" only":"none";};return string.Join("\n",(new[]{"User:   ","Group:  ","Others: "}).Select((c,i)=>c+X(s[i]-'0')));}
```

ungolfed: (with comments)

```cs
string P(string s)
{
    // Function that determines the permissions represented by a single digit (e.g. 4 => "Read only")
    Func<int, string> X = p => 
    {
        var a = new List<string>();         // temporary storage for set permissions
        if ((p & 4) > 0) a.Add("Read");     // Read bit set
        if ((p & 2) > 0) a.Add("Write");    // Write bit set
        if ((p & 1) > 0) a.Add("Execute");  // Execute bit set

        // actually just Output formatting ... Takes a lot of bytes *grr*
        return a.Count > 1 
            ? string.Join(" ", a.Take(a.Count - 1)) + " and " + a.Last() 
            : a.Count > 0 
                ? a.First() + " only" 
                : "none";
    };

    // Actual result:
    return string.Join("\n", (new[] { "User:   ", "Group:  ", "Others: " })
        .Select((c, i) => c + X(s[i] - '0'))); // Map "User, .." to its permissions by using above function
}
```

This is my first time code golfing, so please tell me, if I did anyting wrong :)

## EDIT 1:

Saved some bytes by replacing `s[i]-'0'` by `s[i]&7` (at the very end) and saving list count into variable:

```cs
string P(string s){Func<int,string>X=p=>{var a=new List<string>();if((p&4)>0)a.Add("Read");if((p&2)>0)a.Add("Write");if((p&1)>0)a.Add("Execute");var c=a.Count;return c>1?string.Join(" ",a.Take(c-1))+" and "+a.Last():c>0?a[0]+" only":"none";};return string.Join("\n",(new[]{"User:   ","Group:  ","Others: "}).Select((c,i)=>c+X(s[i]&7)));}
```

## EDIT 2:

Changed to lambda expression:

```cs
s=>{Func<int,string>X=p=>{var a=new List<string>();if((p&4)>0)a.Add("Read");if((p&2)>0)a.Add("Write");if((p&1)>0)a.Add("Execute");var c=a.Count;return c>1?string.Join(" ",a.Take(c-1))+" and "+a.Last():c>0?a[0]+" only":"none";};return string.Join("\n",(new[]{"User:   ","Group:  ","Others: "}).Select((c,i)=>c+X(s[i]&7)));}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 211 bytes

```
{r,w,e,o,a}={"Read ","Write ","Execute ","only ","and "};""<>Transpose@{{"User:   ","Group:  ","Others: "},"None"[{e,o},{w,o},{w,a,e},{r,o},{r,a,e},{r,a,w},{r,w,a,e}][[#]]&/@IntegerDigits[#,10,3],"\n"&~Array~3}&
```

A straightforward implementation (probably easily beatable): doesn't compute anything, just hard-codes each possible output. Input is an integer; outputs each line with a trailing space, and a trailing newline overall.

`IntegerDigits[#,10,3]` gives the three digits of the input (even if there are leading zeros). Each digit indicates an argument of the "function"

```
"None"[{e,o},{w,o},{w,a,e},{r,o},{r,a,e},{r,a,w},{r,w,a,e}]
```

with 0 indicating the function name itself. `""<>` concatenates all the strings in a list (of lists). `"\n"&~Array~3` produces the three newlines.

Comment: I just noticed that my Python 2 answer is almost identical to yours, even using the same variable names. I honestly hadn't seen yours before I posted!

Comment: no worries! I think the variable names' matching is pretty much to be expected in this situation :)

Comment: Guess you're right. The variable names were a bit predictable ☺

Comment: btw, +1 cos we think the same way :-)

Comment: btw, I don't know Mathematica but I think you may be able to lose a byte by removing the space from "only ". It will always be at the end of a line so doesn't need a trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

## C# <s>307</s> <s>241</s> 210 bytes

`string X(string s){var z="User:  ,Group: ,Others:,5,34,14,123,04,023,021,0123,Read,Write,and,Execute,only,None".Split(',');return string.Join("\n",s.Zip(z,(a,b)=>b+z[a-45].Aggregate("",(x,y)=>x+" "+z[y-37])));}`

Formatted

```
string X(string s)
{
    var z = "User:  ,Group: ,Others:,5,34,14,123,04,023,021,0123,Read,Write,and,Execute,only,None".Split(',');
    return string.Join("\n", s.Zip(z, (a, b) => b + z[a - 45].Aggregate("", (x, y) => x + " " + z[y - 37])));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 278

Golfed:

```java
String f(String i){String o="";for(int n=0;n<i.length();)o+=(n<1?"User:   ":n<2?"Group:  ":"Others: ")+new String[]{"None","Execute only","Write only","Write and Execute","Read only","Read and Execute","Read and Write","Read Write and Execute"}[i.charAt(n++)-48]+"\n";return o;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
  String f(String i) {
    String o = "";
    for (int n = 0; n < i.length();)
      o += (n < 1 ? "User:   " : n < 2 ? "Group:  " : "Others: ")
        + new String[] { "None", "Execute only", "Write only", "Write and Execute", "Read only", "Read and Execute",
            "Read and Write", "Read Write and Execute" }[i.charAt(n++) - 48]
        + "\n";
    return o;
  }
```

Output:

```
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read and Write
Others: Read and Write

User:   None
Group:  Read only
Others: Write only

User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read only
Others: Read only
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5, 3.6 - <strike>235</strike> <strike>232</strike> <strike>228</strike> 216 bytes

(should work on all Python 3.x)

So the input is on STDIN here (saves an import ☺).

```python
a=input()
r=range
for i in r(3):
 p=int(a[i]);x=[["Read","Write","Execute"][j]for j in r(3)if 4>>j&p]
 if x[1:]:x[-1:-1]="and",
 if len(x)==1:x+="only",
 print(["User:  ","Group: ","Others:"][i]," ".join(x)or"None")
```

Making use of tuples, omitting spaces where possible and operator precedence where you would normally put parentheses to make your intentions clear.

Sample usage:

```
$ echo -n '666' | python3 golf2.py
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read and Write
Others: Read and Write
$ echo -n '644' | python3 golf2.py
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read only
Others: Read only
$ echo '042' | python3 golf2.py
User:   None
Group:  Read only
Others: Write only
$ echo '123' | python3 golf2.py
User:   Execute only
Group:  Write only
Others: Write and Execute
$ echo -n '777' | python3 golf2.py
User:   Read Write and Execute
Group:  Read Write and Execute
Others: Read Write and Execute
```

Un-golfed:

```python
input_perms = list(map(int, input()))

entities = ["User", "Group", "Others"]
perm_names = ["Read", "Write", "Execute"]

for i in range(3):
    bits = input_perms[i]
    perms = [
        perm_names[j]
        for j in range(3)
        if (1 << (2-j)) & bits
    ]

    if len(perms) > 1:
        perms.insert(-1, "and")
    if len(perms) == 1:
        perms.append("only")

    print("{:7} {}".format(
        entities[i]+":",
        " ".join(perms) or "None"
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 280 bytes

```
@echo off
set/pc=
call:l "User:   " %c:~0,1%
call:l "Group:  " %c:~1,1%
call:l "Others: " %c:~2,1%
exit/b
:l
for %%s in (None.0 Execute.1 Write.2 "Write and Execute.3" Read.4 "Read and Execute.5" "Read and Write.6" "Read Write and Execute.7") do if %%~xs==.%2 echo %~1%%~ns
```

Hardcoding the strings was 47 bytes shorter than trying to piece them together. Would have been 267 bytes if tabs were legal.

Answer (score 1):

## Visual Basic, 606 Bytes

```
imports System.Collections
module h
sub main()
Dim i As String=console.readline()
Dim s=new Stack(new String(){"Others: ","Group:  ","User:   "})
for each j as Char in i
dim t=new Stack()
if((asc(j) MOD 2)=1)then t.push("Execute")
if(asc(j)=50 or asc(j)=51 or asc(j)=54 or asc(j)=55)then t.push("Write")
if(asc(J)>51)then t.push("Read")
if t.count=3 then
w(s.pop+t.pop+" "+t.pop+" and "+t.pop)
else
if t.count=2 then
w(s.pop+t.pop+" and "+t.pop)
else
if t.count=0 then
w(s.pop+"None")
else
w(s.pop+t.pop+" only")
end if
end if
end if
next
end sub
sub w(s As String)
console.writeline(s)
end sub
end module
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first answer BTW :)

Answer (score 1):

## Crystal, <strike>200</strike> 194 Bytes

```
def m(y)y=y.chars.map &.to_i
a=" and "
o=" only"
r="Read"
w="Write"
x="Execute"
c=["None",x+o,w+o,w+a+x,r+o,r+a+x,r+a+w,r+" "+w+a+x]
"User:   "+c[y[0]]+"
Group:  "+c[y[1]]+"
Others: "+c[y[2]]end
```

returns the resulting string for a given octal-sequence as a string.
e.g.: `m("670")` results to: `User:   Read and Write\nGroup:  Read Write and Execute\nOthers: None`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NcnBC4IwFMfx@/6K8Q6hTMQ6FAg7RreCIDrIiDEXCrrJ20T3168ldXg/vnyewuC8HGJs9ZuOWcgDD6XqJLpylBPdld6@eiI5UGlaCsSmsmYIQJDDXcsWyMLhib3XQFYO51Wr@duKN3C1RkOxMlss20m2FpgKfyXZkhYosO0nCDycxprSJKoJTSUEA3JBO0/13/ab3Xyn0dU/OwihTRsn7I3PxgyOpwryPH4A).

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 371 bytes

```cs
public String[] a = {"none","Execute only","Write only","Write and Execute","Read only","Read and Execute","Read and Write","Read Write and Execute"};
public String pA(int i){return a[i];}
public int d(int n,int i){
  n=n/Math.pow(10,i);
  return n%=10;
}
public void main(int i){
  Console.Write("User:\t{0}\nGroup:\t{1},Others:\t{2}",pA(d(i,0)),pA(d(i,1)),pA(d(i,2));
}
```

Comment: This is code-golf, so you must golf your code. Also, add a header with the name of the language and the bytecount.

Comment: I've added your byte count, which is your score. You need to get your score as low as possible to win

Comment: For example, you get rid of all of the unnecessary whitespace in each function

Comment: @BetaDecay Thanks,I'm new to this community and I think I'd better to use php instead which could be  lead to more compacts codes.

Comment: @Alireza That's a good idea. Although on this site, we do like to see short answers in Java and C# :)

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian I don't think you should just abandon a language. For a head start, remove any unnecessary spaces and newlines, and try to use `\t` to denote a literal tab character, i.e. `\t` is one byte, not two.

Comment: I was going to write a C# answer, but yours is actually pretty good with a few modifications. There's quite a bit you can do with this one. You can remove the whitespace, use lambdas and use string interpolation. I was able to get it down to 291 without touching the string array. Although, and this is the problem with C# for golf, if it's a full program that's required it'll jump right back to ~400 because of the namespace and class definitions required to make it execute :/

Answer (score 0):

## PHP ,199 Bytes

```
foreach([User,Group,Others]as$i=>$u){$a=[];foreach([Read,Write,Execute]as$k=>$s)if($argv[1][$i]&4>>$k)$a[]=$s;$a[]=($x=array_pop($a))?$a?"and $x":"$x only":None;echo str_pad("\n$u:",9).join(" ",$a);}
```

PHP ,189 Bytes with \t

```
foreach([User,Group,Others]as$i=>$u){$a=[];foreach([Read,Write,Execute]as$k=>$s)if($argv[1][$i]&4>>$k)$a[]=$s;$a[]=($x=array_pop($a))?$a?"and $x":"$x only":None;echo"\n$u:\t".join(" ",$a);}
```

Comment: Hey, you should use spaces instead of tabs

Comment: In this case \t looks like str_repeat(" ",3-$i) or str_pad("",3-$i," ") but is does not matter with my idea I have no chance to win.If I Should take another space https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

Comment: 13+34 bytes to save.
In the long version:
Use `echo str_pad("$u:",8)` instead of `echo"$u:".str_repeat(" ",3-$i)` (-9);
this renders `$i=>` obsolete (-4).

In both versions:
Use `$a[$z-1]="and $a[$z-1]";` instead of `{$a[]=$a[$z-1];$a[$z-1]="and";}` (-7)
and `else$a[]=$a?Only:None;` instead of `elseif($z<1)$a[]=None;else$a[]=Only;` (-14).

Turn `if(1<$z=count($a))$a[$z-1]="and $a[$z-1]";else$a[]=$a?Only:None;`
into `if($x=array_pop($a))$a[]=$a?"and $x":"$x Only";else$a[]=None;` (-3)
and then into `$a[]=($x=array_pop($a))?$a?"and $x":"$x Only":None;` (-10)

Comment: @Titus echo str_pad("$u:",8),$a[$z-1]="and $a[$z-1]";,else$a[]=$a?Only:None; Done $i=> obsolete I can not do then $m=$argv[1][$i] is necessary. For the rest I would try first another way. Thank You for the input

Comment: meta hint: check the help on comments. You can use mini-Markdown: links, _italic_, **bold** and `code`.

Comment: More ideas: `if(4&$m=$argv[1][$i])` instead of `$m=$argv[1][$i];if(4&$m)` (-3) **OR** replace `$m=;if();if();if();` with a loop: `foreach([Read,Write,Execute]as$k=>$s)if($argv[1][$i]&4>>$k)$a[]=$s;` (-7)

Comment: the foreach loop is a very good idea. my version can't crack your version and maybe we can force your version

Comment: The double ternary assignment can be put inside the join: `join(" ",$a[]=...)` (-3). Leading instead of trailing newline `str_pad("\n$u:",9)` _could_ give another (-3). I think that´s all that can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3.5 - <s>370</s> <s>294</s> 243 bytes

Golfed:

```
import sys
a=lambda o: [print(('User:  ','Group: ','Others:')[n],('None','Execute only','Write only','Write and Execute','Read only','Read and Execute','Read and Write','Read Write and Execute')[int(o[n])]) for n in range(0,3)]
a(sys.argv[1])
```

Size check:

```
$ du -b OctalToHuman.py 
243     OctalToHuman.py
```

Un-golfed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sys import argv as ARGS

types = ('User:  ', 'Group: ', 'Others:')
perms = ('None','Execute only','Write only','Write and Execute','Read only','Read and Execute','Read and Write','Read Write and Execute')

def convert(octal_string):
    for n in range(0,3):
        print(types[n], perms[int(octal_string[n])])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert(ARGS[1])
```

Sample output:

```
$ python ./OctalToHuman.py 666
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read and Write
Others: Read and Write
```

```
$ python ./OctalToHuman.py 042
User:   None
Group:  Read only
Others: Write only
```

```
$ python ./OctalToHuman.py 644
User:   Read and Write
Group:  Read only
Others: Read only
```

Comment: This is not a serious contender for the winning criteria. We require all answers to make a serious attempt at optimizing their score for the winning criteria (for example, in code golf challenges such as this one, submissions must make a serious attempt at minimizing the byte count of the program).

Comment: You can save quite a few bytes by removing `import sys`, and just making the program an anonymous function (`lambda o:`...).

Answer (score 0):

## Sinclair BASIC - <s>263</s> 257 bytes

I did one version using the same approach as everyone else (load of string variables put into array) in 227 bytes, so going to post this one as a different way of doing it.

EDIT - As pointed out, there were some extraneous "and" appearing, this is now resolved

```
1 p=0,z$="and ": INPUT c$
2 FOR EACH a$ IN ["User:   ","Group:  ","Others: "]
3 p+=1,n=VAL c$(p),r=(n & 4)>0,w=(n & 2)>0,x=(n & 1)>0,t=r+w+x
4  ?a$;("Read "*r)+(z$*(r AND (t=2)))+("Write "*w)+(z$*(w AND x))+("Execute "*x)+("only"*(t=1))+("None"*(t=0))
5 NEXT a$
```

Uses bitwise-AND `&` operation to see if the number has 4,2 or 1 bits set and then prints the different permissions. Adding "and" in between multiple values took up most of the space.

Screenshot shows example for 670 as input

[image]

Comment: Does not follow the spec. Your second line should say `Read Write and Execute`. This answer should be non- competing.

Comment: I love Sinclair BASIC. Which interpreter do you use?

Comment: Not sure if someone changed the language name, it's actually SpecBAS which is a more modern version of the original Sinclair BASIC

Answer (score 0):

## F#, <s>204</s> 203 Bytes

*my first golf, so do please forgive any mistakes ;)*

The golfed version (based 1:1 on [pinkfloydx33's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93119/47341)):

```
fun(y:string)->let e,r,w,o,a="Execute ","Read ","Write ","only","and ";let z=["None";e+o;w+o;w+a+e;r+o;r+a+e;r+a+w;r+w+a+e;];let(!-)a=z.[int y.[a]-48];sprintf"User:   %s\nGroup:  %s\nOthers: %s"!-0!-1!-2
```

The ungolfed version:

```
fun (y : string) ->
    let e, r, w, o, a = "Execute ", "Read ", "Write ", "only", "and "
    let z = [
                "None";
                e + o;
                w + o;
                w + a + e;
                r + o;
                r + a + e;
                r + a + w;
                r + w + a + e;
            ]
    let (!-) a = z.[int(y.[a]) - 48]
    sprintf "User:   %s\nGroup:  %s\nOthers: %s" !-0 !-1 !-2
```

Example usage:

```
let k =  ...... // function definition goes here

printf"%s"<|k"755"
printf"%s"<|k"042"
// etc ...
```

---

**This is solely to check, whether I could 'improve' [pinkfloydx33's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93119/47341) - I do not take any credit for the algorithm**

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 191 bytes

```py
def d(n):a,b,c,d,e=' and ',' only',"Execute","Write","Read";l=["None",c+b,d+b,d+a+c,e+b,e+a+c,e+a+d,e+" "+d+a+c];y,u,i=map(int,n);return"User:   %s\nGroup:  %s\nOthers: %s\n"%(l[y],l[u],l[i])
```

ungolfed

```
def d(n):
    a,b,c,d,e=' and ',' only',"Execute","Write","Read"
    l=["None",c+b,d+b,d+a+c,e+b,e+a+c,e+a+d,e+" "+d+a+c]
    y,u,i=map(int,n)
    return"User:   %s\nGroup:  %s\nOthers: %s\n"%(l[y],l[u],l[i])
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! nice first post!

Comment: Hmm, I'm very curious how moderator got 151bytes when I only get 191 :D Is it mistake? Check edits

Comment: That was me, sorry. I typo'ed in the edit. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (ES6), 159 bytes

```
a=>`User:  ${(b=[' None',(c=' Execute')+(d=' only'),(e=' Write')+d,f=e+(g=' and')+c,(h=' Read')+d,h+g+c,h+g+e,h+f])[a[0]]}\nGroup: ${b[a[1]]}\nOthers:`+b[a[2]]
```

---

Example:

```
(a=>`User:  ${(b=[' None',(c=' Execute')+(d=' only'),(e=' Write')+d,f=e+(g=' and')+c,(h=' Read')+d,h+g+c,h+g+e,h+f])[a[0]]}\nGroup: ${b[a[1]]}\nOthers:`+b[a[2]])("042")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl -p, 149 (148+1) bytes

This is a port to Perl of [Firefly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3918/firefly)'s [sed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93112/267).

```
s/(.)(.)/User:   \1                                                             
Group:  \2
Others: /;s/[4-7]/Read $&/g;s/[2367]/Write $&/g;s/[1357]/Execute $&/g;s/0/None/g;s/\w \K(\w+) \d/and $1/g;s/\d/only/g
```

Compared to *sed*:

- Perl uses `$&` instead of `&` *(+ 3 bytes)*.
- Perl has `\d`, which we use instead of `[1-7]` *(-6 bytes)*.
- Perl has `\K` *(-3 bytes)*.
- Perl allows literal newlines in the replacement part of `s///` *(-2 bytes)*.